# SMTP Pro Send Mail Error

Tags: smtp

I am using SMTP pro magento extension.When i check Run Self Test i am getting issues.I am getting following error

```
SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: abc.def@gmail.com from: aaa@gmail.com
Test email was sent successfully.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Testing failed, please review the reported problems and if you need further help visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.
```

Because of this error place order mail is not sending.
Please Help Me.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: You could try posting this issue under https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/issues

Answer (score 4):

I had same problems. Use debug mode for magento and for SMTP Pro. I had to remove the module and it worked.
Log `/var/logs/`

```
app/etc/modules/Rugento_Payment.xml
app/etc/modules/Rugento_Invoicebank.xml
```